# Is there any way to find minimum without the use of derivatve?

Tags: functions, optimization

The function is: $$\sqrt{(x+1)^2+\left(2x^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}$$
It simplifies to: $$\sqrt{4x^4+2x+\frac{17}{16}}$$

Comment: Well, the $x$ which minimizes the square root minimizes $x^4+2x+\frac{17}{16}$, so you can at least ignore the square root part of the problem..

Comment: I don't think your simplification is correct - the coefficient of $x^4$ should be $4$.

Comment: @AmericoTavares No, the $x$ coefficient should be $+2$ as written. Checked using computer algebra (maple).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Geometric Approach

See this as $$\sqrt{(x-(-1))^2+(2x^2-1/4)^2}$$

ie. distance of $(x,2x^2)${a point on curve $y=2x^2$ } from $(-1,1/4)$

That would be **minimum along the normal** to the curve $y=2x^2$ passing through $(-1,1/4)$

Slope of normal through point $(x,2x^2)$ to the curve = $-1/4x$

So, $$-\dfrac1{4x}=\dfrac{2x^2-1/4}{x-(-1)}==>x=-1/2$$

ie. Equating it to the slope of two points $(x,2x^2)$ and $(-1,1/4)$

So, the normal through $(-1,1/4)$ passes through $(-1/2,1/2)$ in the curve $y=2x^2$

Find distance between these points.

Comment: How to calculate the slope of normal without use of derivatives?

Answer (score 0):

I like @exploringnet's solution. Another way to do this is by a bisection algorithm. It might take you a while and is not nearly as elegant.

Let's focus on minimizing $f(x)=2x^4+x$ (a strictly increasing transformation of the original function). Its minimum will be a minimum of the original function.

Start with $f(0)=0$. Note that from $0$ the function is strictly increasing in the positive direction. That will do us no good. Let's move in the negative direction.

$f(-2)=32-2=30$. It's bigger. Moving any further away in the negative direction will do us no good. Go half way between $0$ and $-2$ to $-1$.

$f(-1)=1$. Still bigger than 0. Move half way again to $-\frac{1}{2}$

$f(-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{2}$. Lower now than $0$!

Try $f(-\frac{1}{4})$ and $f(-\frac{3}{4})$. Both are higher than $f(-\frac{1}{2})$

Try $f(-\frac{3}{8})$ and $f(-\frac{5}{8})$. Both are higher than $f(-\frac{1}{2})$

Keep going until you are satisfied $-\frac{1}{2}$ is the minimum.

Comment: Verry dirty soln . What if the solution comes at $(1/2)^{7/5}$ how would you calculate it?We can't keep going until we are satisfied.